# SQL Code optimization

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I have a sql question. Below data I got from the attendance table .
Sometime it has checkin data and sometimes checkout data . Rest it has a null values . I have a Stored procedure which has a cursor which return the output table below(2).

I need to remove the cursor with select statements. so that I can optimize the sql code.Also the table does not have any primary key.
Can you please help me for the same.

Database table snap

```html
 <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4" >
       
        <tr >
            <td >checkIn</td>
            <td >checkout</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td >7/22/2015 11:30</td>
            <td>null</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td >null</td>
            <td>null</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td >null</td>
            <td >7/22/2015 20:30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td >7/21/2015 10:30</td>
            <td>null</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td >null</td>
            <td>null</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td >null</td>
            <td >7/21/2015 14:30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td ></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td ></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>checkin</td>
            <td >checkout<tr>
        <tr >
            <td >7/22/2015 11:30</td>
            <td >7/22/2015 20:30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td >7/21/2015 10:30</td>
            <td >7/21/2015 14:30</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Cursors are not always bad. Static fast_forward cursor is one of the fastest cursor, and sometimes it even out performs while loops. You can try using static fast_forward cursor first before completing moving away from cursor.

Please add more details about Attendance table and stored procedure especially the cursor part. It will help others to understand your problem  better and give an appropriate answer.

Comment: Show the `CURSOR` code and some sample data based on which the `CURSOR` is building the given one.

Comment: It's impossible to give any advice because you haven't given anything to work with. Please include table structures, indexes, row counts and sample data with expected results, preferably in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AttendanceTable]    Script Date: 7/22/2015 1:18:40 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AttendanceTable](
 [CekckInTime] [datetime] NULL,
 [CheckOutTime] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: insert into attendancetable values(getdate(), null)
insert into attendancetable values( null,null)
insert into attendancetable values( null,null)
insert into attendancetable values( null,getdate())

insert into attendancetable values(getdate()-1, null)
insert into attendancetable values( null,null)
insert into attendancetable values( null,null)
insert into attendancetable values( null,null)
insert into attendancetable values( null,getdate()-1)

insert into attendancetable values(getdate()-2, null)
insert into attendancetable values( null,getdate()-2)

Comment: posted the table code and the data which is inserted in table "attendancetable"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and edit your question to make it readable.

Comment: do checkin and checkout belong together because of the same date or what's the logic behind?

Comment: no check in and checkout time will differ , by mistake I have posted the wrong queries I will update the same

Comment: insert into attendancetable values(getdate(), null)
 insert into attendancetable values( null,null) 
 insert into attendancetable values( null,null)
  insert into attendancetable values( null,dateadd(HOUR, 8, getdate())) 
  insert into attendancetable values(getdate()-1, null) 
  insert into attendancetable values( null,null) 
  insert into attendancetable values( null,null) 
  insert into attendancetable values( null,dateadd(HOUR, 8, getdate())-1) 
  insert into attendancetable values(getdate()-2, null) 
  insert into attendancetable values( null,dateadd(HOUR, 8, getdate())-2)

Answer (score 0):

The code I am using is this one , by any chance we can wrap this code in a set of select statements since client suggested to remove cursor from code . Appreciate your help for this post.

```
DECLARE @checkIn varchar(50), @checkOut varchar(50)
CREATE TABLE #LocalTemp
(
 Cekckintime Datetime,
 checkouttime Datetime, 
)
DECLARE @tmpCkin datetime,@tmpCkout datetime

DECLARE cursorName CURSOR 
LOCAL SCROLL STATIC
FOR
    Select Cekckintime, checkouttime FROM attendancetable 
    OPEN cursorName  
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName INTO @checkIn, @checkOut

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            if @checkIn is not null 
                begin
                    set @tmpCkin = @checkIn
                end
            else 
                begin
                    if @checkOut is not null 
                        begin
                            set @tmpCkout =@checkOut
                        end
                end

                if @tmpCkin is not null and @tmpCkout is not null
                begin
                    insert into #LocalTemp values  (@tmpCkin,@tmpCkout)
                    set @tmpCkin = null
                    set @tmpCkout = null
                end
            -- other Bussiness Logic 
           FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName INTO @checkIn, @checkOut
           PRINT @checkIn + ' ' + @checkOut 
        END
        select * from #LocalTemp
        drop TABLE #LocalTemp
CLOSE cursorName 
DEALLOCATE cursorName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can clean up the cursor code by making use of below query this will map the exact checkin Time and checkout time

```
select a.cekckInTime, b.CheckOutTime from 
(select  ROW_NUMBER() Over(  ORDER BY CekckInTime )  as Id, * from  attendancetable where cekckInTime is not null) a 
inner join 
(select  ROW_NUMBER() Over(  ORDER BY CheckOutTime ) as Id, * from  attendancetable where CheckOutTime is not null) b
on a.Id =b.Id
```

Please do let me know if any further optimization is possible.